# Join 2 tables and show sum of a column with it using mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 2 tables containing project data and payment. each of the project may have multiple payment rows.
table 1: projects

```
  id project_name
  1 Test Project
  2 Test Project 2
```

And table 2: project_payments

```
id project_id payment_amount
1       1          100
2       1          200
3       1          100
4       2          150
5       2          200
```

I need to fetch data in the following format

```
project_id payment_id payment amount  total_received
     1          1           100           400
     1          2           200           400
     1          3           100           400
     2          4           150           350
     2          5           200           350
```

That means getting the total_received by the sum of payment amount of each project_id

I have written the following

```
SELECT projects.id as project_id, 
           projects.*, 
           project_payments.*, 
           sum(project_payments.payment_amount) 
FROM projects 
JOIN project_payments on projects.id = project_payments.project_id
```

But it is returning only a single row from each project. How can i get the above data.

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN
`SELECT projects.id as project_id, projects.*, project_payments.*, sum(project_payments.payment_amount) 
FROM projects 
LEFT JOIN  project_payments on projects.id = project_payments.project_id
`

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186532/join-two-tables-based-on-aggregate-function-sum-result) should answer your question

Comment: Its only returning one row

Comment: SUM in an aggregate function, you might need `GROUP BY`, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=6f7c4adc4686060aa827a473e001034e from some examples.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT projects.*, 
       project_payments.*, 
       SUM(project_payments.payment_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY projects.id) total_received
FROM projects
JOIN project_payments ON projects.id = project_payments.project_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&rdbms2=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ed87c2ac05f20097c1272458ecd6e41

PS. MySQL 8+ or MariaDB 10.2+ needed.

Comment: My server is using MariaDB 10.3

Comment: @MuntashirAreRahi the code works for MariaDB 10.3: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0ed87c2ac05f20097c1272458ecd6e41